# How to write bytes to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm porting some Python 2.7 code to 3.10 and I'm having trouble with Bytes vs String.

I have added .encode("utf-8") to all the .startswith and .endswith

The problem I have is at the end, where I get the error

```
...
 destination.write("{}\n".format(delimiter.join(line_tokens)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

How to correct this? Here is my method:

```
def fix_csv_file(csv_file_path, delimiter="\t"):
  temp_file_path = "{}.temp".format(csv_file_path)
  with open(csv_file_path, "rb") as source:
    with open(temp_file_path, "wb") as destination:
      for line in source:
        # Remove carriage return and new line characters.
        if line.endswith("\r\n".encode("utf-8")):
          line = line[:-2]
        elif line.endswith("\n".encode("utf-8")):
          line = line[:-1]
        # Clean up columns.
        line_tokens = line.split(delimiter.encode("utf-8"))
        for idx, token in enumerate(line_tokens):
          token = token.strip()
          if token == "(null)" or token == "\"(null)\"":
            token = "\"\""
          else:
            if not token.startswith("\"".encode("utf-8")) and \
               not token.endswith("\"".encode("utf-8")):
              token = "\"{}\"".format(token)
          line_tokens[idx] = token
        destination.write("{}\n".format(delimiter.join(line_tokens)))
  os.remove(csv_file_path)
  os.rename(temp_file_path, csv_file_path)
```

Comment: Why are you reading a CSV file in binary? Read it in text mode and you don't need all that `.encode()` stuff.

Comment: Either string must be `encode`d to bytes or the file must be opened in text mode and the encoding can be set as argument to "open".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it.

```py
def fix_csv_file(csv_file_path, delimiter="\t"):
    temp_file_path = "{}.temp".format(csv_file_path)
    with open(csv_file_path, "rt") as source:
        with open(temp_file_path, "rt") as destination:
            for line in source:
                if line.endswith("\r\n"):
                    line = line[:-2]
                elif line.endswith("\n"):
                    line = line[:-1]
                line_tokens = line.split(delimeter)
                for idx, token in enumerate(line_tokens):
                    token = token.strip()
                    if token == "(null)" or token == "\"(null)\"":
                        token = "\"\""
                    else:
                        if not token.startswith("\"") \ 
                            and not token.endswith("\""):
                            token = "\"{}\"".format(token)
                    line_tokens[idx] = token
                 destination.write("{}\n".format(delimiter.join(line_tokens)))
    os.remove(csv_file_path)
    os.rename(temp_file_path, csv_file_path)
```

Comment: I did  with open(csv_file_path, "r"). Is there a reason to include `t`?

Comment: Not really  because it is 't' by default